# Domain Data Structures that hold Domain objects?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, encapsulation, ddd-repositories, law-of-demeter

I have a position, and some entities that use position as it's identifier (geography, biome, and so on). If I want to get acess to them, I would need to retrieve each one by it's position, which would cause repeated code. On the other hand, I could create a class that is a container, like a "location". But, in this case, to retrieve geography (for example), I would need to break demeter's law.

```
Repository.getLocation().getGeography().getHighestPeak();
```

Is there any other approach to this, or a common pattern that I'm missing? Keep in mind that this type of objects (that relate to position in the way I described) are very likely to grow large in number after a few months.

Comment: Are you sure that position is suitable to be an ID? Is there a rule that ensures there is only one position for one entity?

Comment: Looks like your root aggregate is way to big.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to have a Position as an ID

- The Position of an entity is likely to change, which leads to an unstable identifier.
- You won't be able to have multiple instances of a given entity with the same position.

> On the other hand, I could create a class that is a container, like a
>   "location". But, in this case, to retrieve geography (for example), I
>   would need to break demeter's law.
>
> Repository.getLocation().getGeography().getHighestPeak();

You're basically saying that a *Location has an entity*, which is a bit awkward. It seems much more natural to say that an *entity has a position*. How about

```
GeographyRepository.getGeographyByPosition(new Position(...)).getHighestPeak();
```

?

Comment: Well, the position of a geometry and a biome won't change. Neither a city and so on.